# create a new array depending on if original array indexes are odd or even

Tags: javascript

Say I have

```
array = [link1, link2, link3, link4]
```

I want to create a new array looking like

```
newArray = [
    {src: link1, width: 4, height: 3},
    {src: link2, width: 2, height: 1},
    {src: link3, width: 4, height: 3},
    {src: link4, width: 2, height: 1}
]
```

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you have so far? Also, how are `width` and `height` determined?

Comment: they are just hard coded ratios dont worry about them, I just want to jump one Item to have them repeated @khan

Comment: i dont see how newArray did anything with its odd/even index.  looks to me like it was just mapped to add the other attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it is:

```
var newArray = [];
var len = array.length;
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    newArray.push({
        src: array[i],
        width: i%2 === 0 ? 4 : 2,
        height: i%2 === 0 ? 3 : 1
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would do it like this, using the modulus operator to detect odd index values.

```js
const array = ['link1', 'link2', 'link3', 'link4'];

const newArray = array.map((item, i) => {
  const odd = i % 2 === 0;
  return {
    src: item,
    width:  odd ? 4 : 2,
    height: odd ? 3 : 1,
  }
});

console.log(newArray);
```